# mouseenter with modal poping up triggering mouseout

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have a lot of pictures displayed with JS in a div. When entering (`mouseover`) a pic, a modal is displayed in the center of the screen, containing the enlarged picture. When `mouseout` from the original picture the modal is set to `display: "none"`. This works all and well, *exept* for the pictures in the middle of the screen: the modal displays *ontop* of the original picture forcing a `mouseout`, and then, since the modal is gone the original picture is once again triggered with `mouseover`, triggering the modal, and so on. This results in a blinking modal; on, off, on, off, on, off...

```
function showBigImg(e) {
var picToShow = e.target.src;
if (picToShow !== replacePic) {
    document.getElementById("insertPic").src = picToShow;
    document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "block";
   }
}


function showSmallImg() {
document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";
}
```

Any suggestions to how I can solve this?

Comment: Add `mouseover` / `mouseout` to the `#modal`

Comment: Not sure why you're listening on the middle area if you use it to show modal. Maybe use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` ?